# Tikz External Library with PGF 3.0

Tags: tikz-external

I just updated to the new PGF version and now I can't externalize my tikzpictures anymore. Does anyone have a similar problem?

Here is some example code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node []    {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Compiling this with "pdflatex --shell-escape file.tex" gives me the following error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\tikzexternal@handle@landscape ...ifpackageloaded 
                                              {pdflscape}{\tikzset { ext...
l.5 \begin{document}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

The complete error log can be found [here](http://textuploader.com/op3r)

Does anyone know how to fix that?!

Comment: Don't you need a `\tikzexternalize` to start it?

Comment: Yes, you would need it for externalizing the images. But it does not work with the command either.

Comment: Your code works without error for me in a current texlive 2014. How did you update to pgf 3.0?

Comment: I am using ubuntu. I delted my texmf directory and created a new one in my home folder. I moved all files from the archive to the folder. Then I run "texhash ~/texmf", as usual.

Comment: Show the complete log-file.

Comment: I added the complete log to the question.

Comment: You don't need to run `texhash` on your home `TEXMF` tree. Which `texmf` directory did you delete? TeX Live 2009 is pretty old. Maybe it is not compatible with PGF 3?

Comment: Update the ltxcmds package. But in such an old system you will probably run in more problems.